# IntelliJ, with neo4j, highlights good methods with red ("cannot resolve")

Tags: intellij-idea, neo4j

I'm running neo4j's "imdb" sample project. It compiles without errors and runs fine.

However, the editor will mark as red ("cannot resolve") some neo4j methods, such as
  Actor.getRelationshipTo()
  Actor.relateTo()

Can I get the editor to stop doing this?

Comment: This is most probably due to issues with the missing AspectJ support in IDEA. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`. If it doesn't help, contact JetBrains support with a sample project to reproduce this problem.